# Variable importance in classification

Tags: statistics, nlp, data-mining

For example: I have 100 books with 1000 words each. They belong to different classes (comedy,drama,...). Each class consist of 15 different books. 
When I do tfidf on my data, I get the importance for every word in a book in context of all books.
I see that the books belonging to the same class have similar tfidf values for each variable.

Let's say drama and comedy are pretty similar. 
How can I tell what words make a difference in between those two classes?
What words do I have to change in book that belongs to comedy so the book now belongs to drama now?

I can check one by one; but I have 2000 books, 17500 words each; 950 classes. It would take a decade :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely run pairwise tests, i.e. one for each of the 475*949 pairs of classes you have as "important variables" can differ very much from case to case. Then run some standard feature selection algorithm, such as chi-square or information gain. See http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/forman03a/forman03a.pdf for an extensive study.

Comment: I have one more question, please. So, if I already have tfidf value for each feature, can I just take two classes (comedy & drama) and do chi-square or random forest only on that? Tfidf already gives me an overall importance of feature for each element.

Answer (score 1):

As a first draft, compute the average vector for each classes, normalize them to unit length, and compute the absolute differences.

These should give you a rough indication of which words distinguish the two classes.

Comment: I thought so too, did that :) was wondering if there is some "smarter" thing to do. Tnx for your answer